# Stripe webhook signature is not present

Tags: c#, stripe-payments, webhooks

I'm trying to integrate stripe webhooks on my website. Initially the application was using only basic stripe and then i've changed it to Stripe Connect, when i was using the basic stripe all webhooks was working well but after changing the usage to Stripe Connect (that actually only adds the connected user ID to the payments) the webhooks stopped to work by returning the following error:

```
Stripe.StripeException: The signature for the webhook is not present in the Stripe-Signature header.
   at Stripe.EventUtility.ValidateSignature(String json, String stripeSignatureHeader, String secret, Int64 tolerance, Int64 utcNow)
   at Stripe.EventUtility.ConstructEvent(String json, String stripeSignatureHeader, String secret, Int64 tolerance, Int64 utcNow, Boolean throwOnApiVersionMismatch)
   at Stripe.EventUtility.ConstructEvent(String json, String stripeSignatureHeader, String secret, Int64 tolerance, Boolean throwOnApiVersionMismatch)
   at VisualOrder.Controllers.WebhookController.Stripe() in E:\VS2019\ccc\Controllers\WebhookController.cs:line 22
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

I've yet changed the webhook key to Connect one, but all sent webhooks return the same error...

Here is my c# code for webhook

```
const string secret = "whsec_kgyb....";
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Stripe()
    {
        
        var json = await new StreamReader(HttpContext.Request.Body).ReadToEndAsync();


        var stripeEvent = EventUtility.ConstructEvent(json,
            Request.Headers["Stripe-Signature"], secret);

        try
        {
            if (stripeEvent.Type == Events.ChargeSucceeded)
            {
                var charge = (Charge)stripeEvent.Data.Object;
                charge.Metadata.TryGetValue("Piva", out string piva);
                charge.Metadata.TryGetValue("OrderId", out string orderID);
                charge.Metadata.TryGetValue("PaymentId", out string paymentID);
                OrdineHelper.ConfirmOrder(piva, orderID, (double)charge.Amount / 100, charge.PaymentIntentId, paymentID);
                return Ok();
            }
            else
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // Invalid Signature
            return BadRequest();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

[This error](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-dotnet/blob/8558bb17/src/Stripe.net/Services/Events/EventUtility.cs#L138-L156) is actually telling you that the *expected* signature is not found, not that *no* signature is found.

Be aware that [Account and Connect webhooks](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/webhooks#connect-webhooks) are two different webhook endpoint and therefore have distinct signing secrets. You either need separate handlers for these or you need to carefully manage which secret you use for each received event. Connect-related events will have an [`account` attribute](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/object#event_object-account), if you are using a mixed handler.

Comment: I know that Account and Connect are two different webhook endpoint and i've yet set the webhook secret key that is in 'Endpoint events from Connected applications', i've just tested the same request in localhost by using stripe CLI with the whsec given by cli and all works fine, but when hosted to the server with secret key got from Dashboard i get the 'no expected signature is found'

Comment: Actually after generating a new webhook secret and putting `var stripeEvent = EventUtility.ConstructEvent(json, Request.Headers["Stripe-Signature"], secret);` inside try catch is working now